# I am trying to make my bot make a new channel with the name of a guild, if it has not already been made

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, this is my bot:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
  const channel = server.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name == guild.id);
  if(channel) return
  if (!channel) {
    client.guilds.cache.map(guild => server.channels.create(guild.id, {type: 'text'})
      .then(async channel => {
        const category = server.channels.cache.get('CHANNELID')
        channel.setParent(category.id)
      })
    )
  }
});
```

It can not find the channels, just spam new channels until I turn it off...

Comment: What are you exactly trying to aim here? Create new channel for each of the guilds? Do you want it to be command? Happen automatically when bot is added to new guild?

Comment: What is `server`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var schannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === message.guild.name); if(!schannel) return message.reply("Channel not found")
```

Comment: You should explain why this works. That will help other people if they have a similar problem (but not the same)